# why kubernetes HA need odd number of master

Tags: kubernetes

I have kubernetes HA environment with three masters. Just have a test, shutdown two masters(kill the apiserver/kcm/scheduler process), then only one master can work well. I can use kubectl to create a deployment successfully ,some pods were scheduled to different nodes and start. So can anyone explain why it is advised odd number of masters? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because if you have an even number of servers, it's a lot easier to end up in a situation where the network breaks and you have exactly 50% on each side. With an odd number, you can't (easily) have a situation where more than one partition in the network thinks it has majority control.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I think if this is the reason, it should like etcd cluster, if there are 3 members and 2 of them are lost, the last one should not work.  In my test, the only one master also works well. That means if the network split to two parts,  both of the masters in the two part will work?

Comment: The two nodes on the majority side of the partition would be able to get quorum for an election (if needed) while the minority side would not, so yes.

Comment: That's up to how you configurated etcd, it does support single-node operation, mostly for testing and demos :)

Comment: In my test, I just kill the master component processes but not etcd members, if I shut down two of three etcd members, the whole kubernetes won't work. Do you mean there is  a configuration in etcd to control this "single-node operation" for kubernetes master components?

Comment: I mean other than etcd, all other components don't need quorum, they either are horizontal services like apiserver or run their own control election like scheduler. I don't really understand your question.

Comment: Okay..Let 's take the scheduler for example. In my test I have three schedulers and then I kill two of them, I expect the control election will like etcd, if lost more than half members, the left cluster won't work.  So I think the only one scheduler left should NOT work, but the test result did not show this.  I can still create a deployment and then the pods were scheduled to other nodes. Any ideas about this behavior?  Thanks for your patient...

Comment: The election happens via etcd, so it relies on that having a stable consensus. Everything related to failure modeling in k8s expects etcd to work correctly :)

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: To have higher fault tolerence for etcd.

Etcd uses [RAFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raft_(algorithm)) for leader selection. An etcd cluster needs a majority of nodes, a quorum, to agree on a leader. For a cluster with n members, quorum is (n/2)+1.

In terms of fault tolerance, **adding an additional node to an odd-sized cluster decreases the fault tolerance**. How? We still have the same number of nodes that may fail without losing quorum however we have more nodes that can fail which means possibility of losing quorum is actually higher than before.

For fault tolerance please check [this](https://etcd.io/docs/v3.5/faq/#what-is-failure-tolerance) official etcd doc for more information.